# Most efficient way to compare Geospatial data in PySpark

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, geospatial

I know in the regular Python shell we can use `pyproj` for example

```
from pyproj import Geod
nyc_geod = Geod(ellps='WGS84')
lat1, lon1 = (70, -74)
lat2, lon2 = (71, -72)
z1,z2,dist = nyc_geod.inv(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2)
dist --> 134163.09514455328
```

And then I can just call on `dist` to give me the distance between the two points. Is there such a function in PySpark, specifically as it pertains to comparing points between two DataFrames? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried googling for "geospatial pyspark" or "geospatial spark" before asking the question? Can you share your research?

Comment: I did, and all it shows me is Magellan. The problem with `pyproj` for me is that it expects a point, not two columns of a DataFrame. I guess the problem is further exacerbated by the fact that PySpark df columns are not iterables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting off with your code slightly reworked so there is a distance function

```
from pyproj import Geod
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nyc_geod = Geod(ellps='WGS84')
def calc_nyc_geod(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2):
  _, _ ,dist = nyc_geod.inv(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2)
  return dist
# show a single point
lat1, lon1 = (70, -74)
lat2, lon2 = (71, -72)
print(calc_nyc_geod(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2))
```

You can make two random DataFrames (here they are with numpy and pandas, but they can come from any source)

```
np.random.seed(1234)
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'lat': np.random.uniform(lat1, lat2, 10),
                    'lon': np.random.uniform(lon1, lon2, 10),
                   }))
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'lat': np.random.uniform(lat1, lat2, 10),
                    'lon': np.random.uniform(lon1, lon2, 10),
                   }))
```

It is hard to tell from your question but it sounds like the goal is to join two different DataFrames and use the distance metric as a criteria. For this case it will just be how many points in df1 are within 35000 meters (?) of df2 (note: this is a full outer join, you can use smarter joins if you already know something about your data). 
To do this you need to make a `UserDefinedFunction` inside of the `SQLContext` object and since DataFrames are typed the output must be typed as well.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
sqlContext.registerFunction("nyc_geod", calc_nyc_geod, DoubleType())
df1.registerTempTable("TDF1")
df2.registerTempTable("TDF2")
sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT COUNT(*) as Overlap FROM TDF1 
JOIN TDF2 
WHERE nyc_geod(TDF1.lon, TDF1.lat, TDF2.lon, TDF2.lat)<35000
""").first()
```

The result is then `Row(Overlap=38)` the number of point pairs (of 100) that meet the criteria.

Comment: How would I go about actually viewing these records?

Edit: Nvm I completely glossed the part where you wrote `as Overlap`, thanks so much I will certainly use this as a basis.